# Transformer covers: Do these actually work in blocking RF/etc coming from the transformer?

Tags: transformer

Transformer covers: Do these actually work in blocking RF/etc coming from the transformer? I found one while browsing through Audiofonics.fr.

[image]

Comment: You will find some useful information [here](https://durenberger.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/mil-hdbk-419a-grounding.pdf). Go to about page 240 or so and read forward from there. They discuss the plane wave theory of shielding.

Comment: Shielding a transformer with a magnetic material (e.g. iron) helps to block the radiated EMI from the transformer. Toroidal transformers hardly need shielding as they inherently radiate less.

Comment: That will be a good electrostatic shield, from the potentials on the secondary winding. For some sensitive applications, you need all the screening you can get. It counts for nothing though if you have non-shileded mains wires going intot he transformer.

Comment: Impossible to say without a link to the data sheet. It looks plastic to me and herein lies the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this is a good magnetic conductor (typically mu-metal if we are talking about serious shielding), this will significantly confine LF magnetic fields from the transformer.  This makes mostly sense as a "papering-over" solution for setups where signal traces are not properly paired with ground traces (which are separated from power supply grounds and ground pours) and signal sums are not accompanied with ground bus sums.

The disadvantage over making the circuit impervious to hum injection by avoiding significant areas that would behave problematically when crossed by magnetic fields is that external field sources (like overland lines or motors or transformers nearby) will still impact the circuitry.

Ring transformers in particular have comparatively low external fields already, and if one is mounted in the same plane as the circuit board, its remaining electric and magnetic fields will be oriented in a manner where they will have almost no effect on traces on the circuit board.

Answer (score 1):

If it is pressed steel, it is much more likely to be designed to reduce low frequency magnetic leakage (though this is already low with toroidal transformers) and inductive pickup, rather than true radiated RFI.

This extra shielding can be useful in audio / LF applications to reduce hum pickup if there are loops in signal paths (or ground returns).

For true RFI shielding you would expect electrically conductive mating surfaces, the case would enclose a whole circuit rather than just the transformer, and there should be ground connection points.

Comment: it's made of steel

Comment: In that case it is almost certainly intended to reduce LF magnetic interference.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't assign motive to a material that is also very cheap, easily manufactured, and reasonably strong. But magnetic shielding is an often-welcome side effect of using steel.

Comment: Worth noting that cases like this only have the mounting bolt through the middle of one part, and the other part is fixed at the corners.  If you bolt through both parts with a conductive bolt you risk creating a shorted turn round the core.  The case will then get very hot, very quickly!

Comment: @TimWilliams Agree that they are often just used for mechanical protection when the toroid is externally mounted for cooling.

Comment: @colintd trying to visualize this statement " If you bolt through both parts with a conductive bolt you risk creating a shorted turn round the core" but nothing is coming. Are you saying I need to have maybe rubber/tape/something in between the 2 parts to electrically separate them? Thanks again!

Comment: The case as designed, with the "lid" attached at the corners, is fine.  However, if you were to put a conductive bolt all the way through the middle, touching both case parts, you could create a shorted turn.  Don't do that, and there is no issue.

Comment: @colintd another question please: do I need to connect the cover to earth ground? Thanks

Comment: I would think so, as all exposed metalwork should be grounded for safety purposes. Grounding won't however impact the magnetic shielding either way